# URL incorrectly redirecting to other site hosted on same server (nginx)

Tags: nginx, ssl, virtual-machines, vagrant

I have an Ubuntu VM running nginx that I'm part way through configuring for SSL.

I've defined some custom local domains that I use for development, stored in my hosts file (on the host machine, which is OSX):

```
192.168.50.50   foo.dev
192.168.50.50   www.foo.dev

192.168.50.50   bar.dev
192.168.50.50   www.bar.dev
```

Each has its own config file, both act to redirect all traffic to the non-www SSL domain.

The nginx config for foo.dev looks like:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name www.foo.dev;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/foo.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/foo.key;

  return 301 https://foo.dev$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name foo.dev;

  return 301 https://foo.dev$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name foo.dev;

  root /var/www/foo;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/foo.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/foo.key;
}
```

And here's bar.dev's nginx config:

```
upstream bar_upstream {
  server 127.0.0.1:4000;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name www.bar.dev;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/bar.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/bar.key;

  return 301 https://bar.dev$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name bar.dev;

  return 301 https://bar.dev$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name bar.dev;
  root /var/www/bar/priv/static/;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://bar_upstream;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
  include /etc/nginx/h5bp/location/expires.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/h5bp/location/cross-domain-fonts.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/h5bp/location/protect-system-files.conf;
}
```

The problem is that visiting bar.dev in my browser causes a redirect to foo.dev. This happens in all browsers, I've tried flushing the cache, restarting nginx and have done a configtest.

I've combed both files for typos and incorrect references.

I'm new to nginx, so forgive me if it's something obvious?

Comment: Do you mean redirection? There is no such thing as "URL forwarding".

Comment: Well semantically it made perfect sense, but yes, good catch, better for indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is worth keeping alive for others, but it did end up being an obvious error, `bar.dev` didn't have its `listen 443 ssl;`, it had two `listen 80;`s.

So a working bar.dev config:

```
upstream bar_upstream {
  server 127.0.0.1:4000;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name www.bar.dev;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/bar.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/bar.key;

  return 301 https://bar.dev$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name bar.dev;

  return 301 https://bar.dev$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name bar.dev;
  root /var/www/bar/priv/static/;
  location / {
    proxy_pass https://bar_upstream;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
  include /etc/nginx/h5bp/location/expires.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/h5bp/location/cross-domain-fonts.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/h5bp/location/protect-system-files.conf;
}
```